# Types of blur method in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on creating a deep learning model for detecting blur objects in an image.

For that, I need to create a dataset of blur objects. I want to do it automatically using OpenCV.

So I want to apply all methods to create a good dataset. I only found the following methods to blur something in Python so far.

I can also use other library than OpenCV, if you suggest some.

```
def blurface(img):
    num = random.randint(1,4)

    if num == 1:
        img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (random.randrange(111, 190+1, 2),random.randrange(111, 190+1, 2)), random.randrange(111, 190+1, 2))
    if num == 2:
        img = cv2.medianBlur(img, random.randrange(71, 277+1, 2)) 
    if num == 3:
        img = cv2.blur(img,(random.randint(90,190),random.randint(90,190)))
    if num == 4:
        imgshape = img.shape
        img = cv2.resize(img,(random.randint(4,9),random.randint(4,9)))
        img = cv2.resize(img,(int(imgshape[1]),int(imgshape[0])),interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

    return img
```

Currently, I use 4 methods to blur

1.) GaussianBlur, medianBlur, blur & decrease size & increase size blur.

**Also, how can I blur in different shapes? Circle, oval, random shape etc?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use variance over laplacian for the blur detection as described here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/

It's much faster and easier than applying Deep Learning.

Comment: but it cannot detect the location of blur, Can it? Maybe... I am noob at maths...Thanks, i will try this also

Comment: Like, Only If face is blurred.

Comment: @Rahul split your image into sections and check every section separately. or detect faces and check only those regions.

Comment: I tried this. not working very good....A lot of edge cases, that do not seem possible to fix manually or not worth it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how are you detecting blur regions with deep learning.

1. You can keep two classes, one with only blurred images of different kind and another without any blurring. This is a simple classification problem and should give you a good accuracy. A slightly complex variation would be the model will also classify which kind of blur is used.
2. For each image, you are trying to predict the actual blurred region. It's a localization problem and harder to model. You need to create your dataset with Yolo-like object detection model.

I think the problem is with your deep learning model as detecting blur region should not be extremely hard problem. I would suggest doing hard blurring to check if your deep learning model actually works.

As far as other shapes,

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
h, w, c = img.shape

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

c_mask = np.zeros((h,w), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(c_mask,(w//2,h//2),100,1,thickness=-1)

mask = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=c_mask)

plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()

img_mask = img - mask

plt.imshow(img_mask)
plt.show()

blur = cv2.blur(img,(17, 17))


plt.imshow(blur)
plt.show()

mask2 = cv2.bitwise_and(blur, blur, mask=c_mask)

plt.imshow(mask2)
plt.show()

final_img = img_mask + mask2

print(np.max(final_img))

plt.imshow(final_img)
plt.show()
```

You can change the geometric object (mask) to get more shapes.

[image]

Comment: Hey, the deep learning model works. But there are a lot of filters that people use using photoshop etc etc....I want to create a good dataset.

Comment: is it a simple classification dataset? or you're planning to add localization too?

Comment: I don't care about localization. But i want to know, if the image is intentionally blurred or not. So I guess, localization will help